# Inserting Array into a mysql field

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am the facebook api graph to get a list of all of my friends id's.

I would like to put all of those id's into one field in my database.

Here is my code so far:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
foreach($friends['data'] as $friend) {
$friend_list = $friend['id'].',';
}           
$query = "INSERT INTO users
(id, 
first_name ,
last_name ,
friends
)
VALUES (
'$id', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$friend_list' )";

mysql_query($query);
```

I'm sure you guys can see what is going on here. It creates a new row for each id and fills it in the other three values.

I'm being a bit of a space cadet on trying to solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to put all of those id's into one field in my database.

That doesn't sound like a good idea. You would have to use something like comma separated values, but that is inefficient for searching because an index cannot be used.

You should create a separate table to model the relationship between users:

```
user_friend
user   friend
1      15
1      135
1      254
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing this was just concerned with how many rows it would be creating over time. Average people have around 500-1000 friends. So every new signup would be creating 500-1000 rows...